# Pagination with OFFSET FETCH NEXT not return any rows

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to paging row data with `offset @offset row fetch next @numRowWantToGet rows only` but it not return any rows.
[Here](https://pastebin.com/PKbi3jq9) is my main code to get data in procedure:

```
DECLARE @return_value int,
        @maxRows int

SELECT  @maxRows = -1

EXEC    @return_value = [hac_db_cloned].[pGetCard]
        @inputcardid = N'',
        @offsetRow = 0,
        @numRows = 20,
        @maxRows = @maxRows OUTPUT

SELECT  @maxRows as N'@maxRows'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

And this is return Message:

(20 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)

Result: @maxRows = 63, Return value = 0
System: SQL Server 2014 Express

Comment: Avoid nested subqueries, makes the statement very hard to read (use CTEs instead). If your query returns 0 rows means that you are fetching ahead of your limit, or the query that's calculating the final amount is actually different from the one thats selecting them. Include in your post the query that's actually running with the parameters you are actually passing to the SP.

Comment: I've updated my code and add my proc call